# DB is still writable after changing to read only

Tags: mariadb

I'm trying to make DB read-only for MariaDB, but it is not working correctly until we restart the service (Spring Boot application). The service keeps writing the data until we restart.

How can we make DB read-only so that it immediately stops writing regardless of service restart?

I tried commands:

1.

```sql
FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK; 
SET GLOBAL read_only = 1;
```

2. 

```sql
FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
```

None of the above fulfills the requirement. Please suggest if there's a different approach to do that.

Comment: *`SET GLOBAL read_only = 1; `* This effects only on newly created connections. *Please suggest if there's a different approach to do that.* Create a role with read permission and a role with full permission which is set as default. When you need tyo lock the tables then set RO role as default.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/revoke/